# Fix an item in a ObservableScrollView Android

Tags: android, scrollview, material-design, googleio

I'm trying to fix an item in a ScrollView when it hit the ActionBar.
It stop correctly but when i return to main scroll position, i get a random margin above the layout (Screenshot 3). (The margin in Screenshot 2 is not a bug)

[image: Problem screenshot]

My ObservableScrollView listener

```
if(t > stackHeight && !animationActionBarstackedBg){
                animationActionBarstackedBg = true;
            } else if (t < stackHeight && animationActionBarstackedBg){
                animationActionBarstackedBg = false;
            }

            frameImg.setPadding(frameImg.getPaddingLeft(), t/2, frameImg.getPaddingRight(), frameImg.getPaddingBottom());

            if(animationActionBarstackedBg){
                panelTitleContainer.setPadding(panelTitleContainer.getPaddingLeft(), t-stackHeight, panelTitleContainer.getPaddingRight(), panelTitleContainer.getPaddingBottom());
            }
```

Where t is the ScrollY, stackHeight is the image height, frameImg is a FrameLayout containing an ImageView (to make a Google I/O 2014 like animation) and panelTitleContainer is a layout which contains the brown layout.

There is a way to fix an item in a scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `setTranslationY()`

```
if(t > stackHeight && !animationActionBarstackedBg){
    animationActionBarstackedBg = true;
} else if (t < stackHeight && animationActionBarstackedBg){
    animationActionBarstackedBg = false;
}

frameImg.setTranslationY(svMain.getScrollY() * 0.5f);

if(!animationActionBarstackedBg){
    panelTitleContainer.setTranslationY(0);
} else {
    panelTitleContainer.setTranslationY(svMain.getScrollY() - stackHeight);
}
```